# Reta de regressão ajustada considerando diferentes fatores no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, regressão

Estou tentando reproduzir o gráfico abaixo, em que as retas internas são as retas de regressão ajustadas:

[image]

No entanto, por algum fator não está sendo plotado o que deveria, ou seja, está sendo apresentado uma única reta, e mais, as diferentes concentrações da variável "teor" não estão sendo plotadas como na imagem acima, veja o resultado abaixo:

[image]

```
dados = read.table("datanew.csv", header = T, sep=";", dec=","); head(dados)
dados$Trat <- factor(dados$Trat)
dados$Teor <- factor(dados$Teor)
dadosnew$Tempo = as.factor(dadosnew$Tempo)

my.formula <- y ~ x
p = ggplot(dadosnew, aes(x = Tempo, y = massaseca, group = Fator)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "point", fun = mean) + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE,  formula=y ~ poly(x, 2, raw=TRUE)) + stat_poly_eq(formula = my.formula,
                                                                                         eq.with.lhs = "As-italic(hat(y))~`=`~",
                                                                                         aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "*plain(\",\")~")), 
                                                                                         parse = TRUE, size = 5, label.y = 35)+
  labs(title = "",
       x = "Time (Minutes)",
       y = "Weight (mg)") + theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 23,color="black"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 18,color="black"),
        text = element_text(size = 50,color="black"),
        legend.position = "none") + facet_wrap(~Fator)
p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, para ler os dados é melhor, mais simples, usar a função `help("read.csv")`, que é a versão de `read.table` para ficheiros CSV com `sep = ";"` e `"dec = ","`. Nos ficheiros CSV há sempre nomes de coluna, portanto `header = TRUE`.
Além disso, converto todas as colunas de classe `"character"` para fator com um vetor de nomes de colunas a converter, não é necessário fazê-lo uma a uma.

```
dados <- read.csv2("datanew.csv")

i <- c("Trat", "Teor")
dados[i] <- lapply(dados[i], factor)
```

Agora o gráfico.
Retirei o `stat_poly_eq` porque se há 5 níveis de `Trat` para cada `Fator`, teríamos 5 equações em cada faceta e o gráfico fica mais difícil de ler.

```
library(ggplot2)

shape_brks <- unique(dados$Trat)
shape_vals <- rep(c(0, 2:5), 2)

p <- ggplot(dados, aes(x = Tempo, y = massaseca, shape = Trat)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "point", fun = mean) +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE,
              formula = y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE),
              linetype = "dashed", 
              size = 0.5) +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Trat", 
                     breaks = shape_brks, 
                     values = shape_vals) +
  labs(title = "",
       x = "Time (Minutes)",
       y = "Weight (mg)") +
  facet_wrap(~ Fator) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 23, color = "black"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 18, color = "black"),
        text = element_text(size = 50, color = "black"),
        legend.position = "none")
p
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]